# $G=HK$ then the index of a subgroup is determined by $H$ and $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=HK$ s.t. $H\cap K=1$ and let $R$ be a any subgroup of $G$.

I wonder necessary and suffucient condition for the equality,

$$|G:R|=|H:H\cap R||K:K\cap R|$$

Note that if $H$ and $K$ are normal and $(|H|,|K|)=1$ then above equality is true, which can be proven easily.

Comment: Let $G=S_3$, $H= \langle (1,2,3) \rangle$, $K = \langle (1,2) \rangle$, $R = \langle(1,3)\rangle$. Then  $|G:R|=3$, $|H:H\cap R|=3$, $|K:K \cap R|=2$, so your note is not correct. It would work if $H$ and $K$ were both normal in $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: sorry I edited it.

Comment: I conjecture that $H$ and $K$ both normal and $(|H|,|K|)=1$ are necessary and sufficient conditions for the conclusion to hold for all subgroups $R$ of $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $G=HK$ with $H \cap K=1$. Then (assuming $G$ is finite), the conclusion holds for all subgroups $R$ if and only if $H,K \unlhd G$ and $(|H|,|K|)=1$.

You can do the "if" part. For the "only if" part, if $H \not\unlhd G$, then there exists $k \in K \setminus N_G(H)$, and the conclusion fails for $R = k^{-1}Hk$. Similarly if $K \not\unlhd G$.

If $H,K \unlhd G$ (so $G \cong H \times K$), but $(|H|,|K|) \ne 1$, then there is a prime $p$ dividing both $|H|$ aand $|K|$, and the conclusion fails for $R = \langle hk\rangle$, where $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ both have order $p$.